# Knitting/Rendering R Markdown Output: Can I prevent code from showing in PDF output but allow code folding in HTML output?

Tags: html, r, pdf, output, r-markdown

Showing the code in PDF can be long and distracting to some readers or clients, but I would leave it as an option in the HTML version if they want to reproduce it or verify what I've done. Depending on whom I work with, I may share one or the other (or both), but I want to avoid changing the Rmd script each time to produce them.

Thus, I want to be able to knit my R Markdown script to HTML and PDF in a way so that the HTML output can show the code (with `code_folding` in the `output: html_document` options), but prevent the code from appearing in my PDF output.

Is there a way to do that without recoding part of the script each time?

Take this example R Markdown text:

````
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    df_print: kable
  html_document:
    code_folding: show
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r mtcars}
# I want to make this code visible when I knit to HTML, but hidden when I knit to PDF. 
# How do I do that?
mtcars[1:2, 1:4]
```
````

It will show the `mtcars` chunk when it's knitted.

I can change `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)` to `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)` in the setup chunk to prevent the code from showing in the PDF output, but the code will disappear in the HTML output as well.

`code_folding: hide` can hide the code for `html_document` output options and allows the reader to see the code if necessary. However, `code_folding: hide` does not work for `pdf_document` output options. Is there an alternative that I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use `is_html_output` in `eval` and `echo`

````
---
title: "Title"
output: 
 html_document:
   code_folding: show
   df_print: paged
  pdf_document:
    df_print: kable
 ---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r mtcars, eval = knitr::is_html_output(), echo = knitr::is_html_output()}
# I want to make this code visible when I knit to HTML, but hidden when    I knit to PDF. 
 # How do I do that?
 mtcars[1:2, 1:4]
 ```
````

-output html

[image]

-output pdf

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! I didn't know about that function. By extension, instead of applying to every chunk, I can apply it to the code in the `setup` chunk to change the default behaviour: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = knitr::is_html_output())`.